# How to create new Object or Cloning of ListGrid in Smart Client

Tags: smartclient

I want to create an object of **ListGrid** component in Smart Client.

```
isc.ListGrid.create({
  ID: "countryList",
   width:500, height:224, top:50, alternateRecordStyles:true,
   fields:[
     {name:"countryCode", title:"Flag", width:50, type:"image", imageURLPrefix:"flags/16/", imageURLSuffix:".png"},  
     {name:"countryName", title:"Country"},  
     {name:"capital", title:"Capital"},  
     {name:"continent", title:"Continent"}  
]}) ;
```

Now countryList is the ID for the **ListGrid** component .

Let us suppose that this Grid has possess some values and i want to put some other values like values from database and there is a condition that we don't have to override or change previous values.So we need to create a new object of **countryList** .

> How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand if you need another instance of the same ListGrid, or if you need to display different data in the same ListGrid.

If you need another instance, you could define a class:

```
isc.defineClass("MyGrid", "ListGrid");
isc.MyGrid.addProperties({
  width:500, height:224, top:50, alternateRecordStyles:true,
  fields:[
    {name:"countryCode", title:"Flag", width:50, type:"image", imageURLPrefix:"flags/16/", imageURLSuffix:".png"},  
    {name:"countryName", title:"Country"},  
    {name:"capital", title:"Capital"},  
    {name:"continent", title:"Continent"}  
  ]
});
isc.MyGrid.create({ID: "countryList"});
isc.MyGrid.create({ID: "countryList2"});
```

Otherwise, if you need to show different data in the same ListGrid instance, you could do:

- countryList.setData(newData); // or:
- dataSource.fetchData(criteria, "countryList.setData(data)"); // or:
- countryList.fetchData(newCriteria); // if countryList has a dataSource attribute

Comment: i have a list grid with more than 75 fields.Now i made a method having parameter is array of List Grid (var array=ListGrid_ID.getRecord(index);) and i want to use same method for data coming from database,So i need to keep theDB value into new Instance of ListGrid.And i don't know how to make new Instance.

Comment: i had also tried the above approach that you wrote above but it is showing two list grids  on the same screen .i need two object but only on list grid on screen.